# Search for text in IntelliJ only in files with specific prefix

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, search, prefix

Pretty sure this can be done with Search Everywhere using a rejex, I want to find all instances of a word, for example "productCode", but only in files beginning with "Market..."

This is important because "productCode" is a field that is found in many files, and I am looking for specific uses only.
Thanks!

I am using IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Use Find in Path for this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use this option from the drop-down menu:

```
Edit -> Find in Path...
```

Then search as follows:

[image: screen capture]

This will search for content `\bproductCode\b` appearing in any file starting with `Market`, anywhere in your project.